# JQuery get values from non standard html tags in IE7

Tags: jquery, xml

I have some HTML on which I need to get the values from. But it doesn't work in IE7.

```
// JQuery, works in Chrome, FF, IE8 >
$('#price-xml').find('voorraad').html()

// HTML
<span style="display: block;" id="price-xml">
  <pricestock>
    <vp>
      <nettovp>164,46</nettovp>
      <nettovpincl>199,00</nettovpincl>
      <brutovp>164,46</brutovp>
      <brutovpincl>199,00</brutovpincl>
      <orivp>164,46</orivp>
      <orivpincl>199,00</orivpincl>
      <korting1>0</korting1>
      <korting2>0</korting2>
      <soortprijs>A</soortprijs>
    </vp>
    <tel>
      <voorraad>4</voorraad>
      <inbacklev>0</inbacklev>
      <inbackkla>1</inbackkla>
      <consign>0</consign>
      <magctrl>0</magctrl>
      <inprod>0</inprod>
      <opaflever>0</opaflever>
      <voorrres>0</voorrres>
      <voorzprod>0</voorzprod>
    </tel>
  </pricestock>
</span>
```

Comment: Are these custom tags?

Comment: Did you try to add a css property like _pricestock { display: block; }_ like html5shiv?.

Comment: Yes these are just custom tags inside a html page

Tried with display: block, no changes.

@JqueryKing I don't really understand what yo mean